# Why is this code rewrite elements of char array in every loop?

Tags: c, arrays, character

I would like to create a hangman game. I filled a char array with '*' characters, than scan a char from the user, and if the character matches with any of the characters with previously defined word, it swaps the  '*' char to the correct letter.

But my code rewrites the correct letters to '_' in every loop, and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define words_num 4

int i ;


char a[length]  ;

char guess;

while(1) {

printf("Guess a letter \n") ;

scanf(" %c", &guess) ;

hangman( guess, words[chosen] , a, length ) ;

}


printf("\n") ;
system("pause") ;
}

void hangman (char guessed, char words[], char a[] , int length ){


for (i = 0; i < length ; i++ ) {

a[i] = '_' ;
}

for (i=0; i< length ; i++) {

if (guessed == words[i]) {

    a[i] = guessed ;
}
}

for(i=0; i< length; i++) {
printf("%c ", a[i]) ;
}

}
```

Comment: It seems that part of the source is missing.

Comment: This does not compile.

Comment: You are overwriting a[i] each time hangman() is called with ` a[i] = '_' ;
`, you just need to do that once during setup before asking for guesses  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite clearly since the code to fill `a` with underscores is at the start of `hangman()`, so it will be run on each call from `main()`. Move that code to the start of `main()`, before the `while`.

Comment: Obviously it is not so clear to the OP, so it is not quite clearly... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , the code missing partly, sorry, here is the corrected code.

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define words_num 4

int i ;


int main() {

char *words[20] = { "apple" , "window", "cat" , "dog" };

srand(time(NULL)) ;

int chosen = rand() % words_num ; /* A választott */

printf("%s\n", words[chosen]) ;

int length = strlen(words[chosen]) ;

printf("Length is:  ") ;
printf("%d\n", length) ;



char a[length]  ;

char guess;

for (i = 0; i < length ; i++ ) {

a[i] = '_' ;
}

while(1) {

printf("Guess a letter \n") ;

scanf(" %c", &guess) ;

hangman( guess, words[chosen] , a, length ) ;

}


printf("\n") ;
system("pause") ;
}

void hangman (char guessed, char words[], char a[] , int length ){

for (i=0; i< length ; i++) {

if (guessed == words[i]) {

    a[i] = guessed ;
}
}

for(i=0; i< length; i++) {
printf("%c ", a[i]) ;
}

}
```